# Grouping data where each cluster has a similar sum of a variable?

Tags: clustering

I have a data set of postcode areas and their populations. I would like to cluster the data set in a way in which each cluster has roughly the same population of 80,000. Phrasing mathematically I'd like to minimize the sum of the norms of (populations of each cluster - 80,000).

How would I go about this? I have researched unsupervised clustering but all those methods effectively aim to minimize within and between cluster similarity.

Comment: That's quite a large topic, so I'm a bit reticent to write a full-blown answer, but I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5452702/5556711). There's certainly better ways, and you might enjoy [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6984299) on clustering with size constraints if you're interested in another perspective, but the first link should do the job.

Comment: If I used the first method how would I initially create the clusters since k-means requires a distance metric but if population is used it would group areas with similar populations. The best method I can think of is an alteration of the first fit algorithm where if an area can't fit in a cluster you'd create a new one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, I thought that you meant cluster size of 80,000. Using an agglomerative clustering algorithm (a type of [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering)), start with all observations as independent clusters, then merge clusters based on whatever notion of distance you want, but don't merge if population goes over your desired limit. This is if you want a "hard" constraint on population size. Otherwise, you can incorporate population over/under 80,000 in the linkage criterion (you can read about it in the link).

Comment: Good idea. The similarity could be |population if clusters are merged  -  80,000| and pick the best possible similarity to merge with if  |population if clusters are merged  -  80,000| < min of the |population of clusters before merger   -  80,000|.